# OpenCL - Main Kernel filling buffers and run on sub kernels

Tags: opencl, kernel

Being new to OpenCL i would like to know if the following scenario is possible.

In memory there are created 10 buffers of length 10000, or a 10xN image buffer working as cache.

The first kernel are to fill in a row in the cache and query another kernel to do some work on that row. When the second kernel is done, the first kernel can compute a new row and replace the old one and the same procedure continues until the first kernel have no more tasks.

Does the scenarie makes sense and is it posible within GPU programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCL does not allow kernels to call other kernels.  But you have some options.

1. Have the first kernel call another non-kernel function.  Work distribution between work items will not change here - so if you have 10 parallel work items (threads) being executed, one on each row, then each thread will operate on the same data in the non-kernel function.
2. Multiple kernels can be enequeued one after another, but this is coordinated by the host.  This does allow redistribution of work among threads, but can be more complicated to do than option 1.

One of the keys to creating fast OpenCL code is splitting your work into work items, usually the more the better.  If your first kernel that fills the row can only be split into 10 work items, but your second kernel that does processing on this row can be split up into 1000s of work items, then you definitely want to use option 2 as the second part can be more efficiently split up on devices with large number of cores such as modern GPUs.  A small number of work items, such as 10, will only be able to use a fraction of this available processing power.

(Additions)

OpenCL kernels executing on GPUs are data parallel, which means only one kernel can execute at a time but each thread works with a different piece of data.  It might be worth rethinking your algorithm to fit in this model.

From what you have written in your comments it sounds like that you want to run 10 items at a time because of memory constraints.  But be aware that there is no dynamic memory allocation in OpenCL.  All buffers are declared up front.  So the host should determine how many tasks could fit into available memory and run batches of work items (with appropriate transfer of buffers).

Also how are the buffers being filled in?  From files?  OpenCL kernels cannot read files, network, etc. so if this is how the original data is loaded this will have to be done on the host.  If, however, these image buffers are created from other sources (e.g. by an algorithm or from another in-memory source) then that should work OK (though you'd need to copy any other in-memory sources to the GPU as well).

Comment: That is exactly my case. The ratio of work items is 1:2000 for the first and second task described above. So option 2 is the answer to my question. I mentioned 10 rows in my example as i need some buffer to keep the data for the second task, and the memory demand would be to big if it just started doing all tasks. So if there is N tasks for the first kernel, is it possible to tell only to run 10 work items at the same time and only continue a new work item whenever the second task completes?

Comment: I am also thinking about just keeping the first task on the host and write the input data to gpu and enqueue the second task and when its done read the results and write a new set of inputs to the gpu and enqueue again.  But if the first task also could be made on the gpu i would not need to write from host to gpu that much.

Comment: @s093294 different GPU hardware will have different performance.  Keeping the first task on the host might work out being faster depending on how long it takes to copy memory from host to device, which depends on the device, host and amount of memory that needs to be copied.  You might want to try both and pick the one that ends up being the fastest with your hardware.

Comment: So if there is N tasks for the first kernel, is it possible to tell it only to run 10 work items at the same time and only continue a new work item whenever the second task completes? Is this work-group related. If i did set the local size to be 32, would this mean it runes 32 threads and only start new once when others complete. And could i then add a memory berrier or something to make it wait for the second task?

Comment: @s093294 added more details to the answer

Comment: Sounds goood - the buffers are filled with data generated from the first task. It is a set of random numbers. So the only thing i am not 100% clear about now is the question about work-group size. If the host decides that 10, then it should enqueue the kernel with global size of 10 and then when those 10 are done it can query another 10, correct ?

Comment: @s093294 if the global size is set to 10, then there will only be 10 threads executing.  If, after 10 have executed, you want to execute another 10, this needs to be coordinated on the host.  You can enqueue the same kernel multiple times before kicking everything off which will cause the work items to be processed in batches of 10.